# In PHP fgetcsv converts file into one array

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have a csv file I'm uploading that is structured like this:

```
SKU,STATUS,SUPPLIER,PRODUCT TYPE,PRODUCT SUBTYPE,PRODUCT STYLE,PRODUCER NAME,PRODUCT NAME,VINTAGE,RAW MATERIALS
00788305,Active,Pabst Brewery,Beer,Specialty,Spice/Herb/Vegetable,Small Town Brewery,Not Your Father's Root Beer (Units of 4),,
00380314,Active,The Patr¢n Spirits Company,Spirit,Tequila,Extra A§ejo,Patr¢n,En Lalique Serie 1 Extra A§ejo Tequila,,
00255814,Active,Huneeus Vintners,Wine,Still,White,Veramonte,Valle de Casablanca Chardonnay,,Chardonnay
```

The csv was created from an excel spreadsheet export.

When I run fgetcsv against the uploaded file I get one long array instead of each line placed into its own array as expected.

Comment: did you tell php what kind of line breaks the file is using?

Comment: From the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php): `Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.`

Comment: @MarkBaker - I did that and `print_r` only prints out the first array (line)

Comment: fgetcsv() returns one line at a time, you have to loop doing an fgetcsv() for each line until end of file

Comment: @MarkBaker - yep! figured that out right after I said it. lol

Comment: @MarkBaker - if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> **Note:** If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

`fgetcsv()` will only read one row at a time, so you will need to loop over the file calling `fgetcsv()` to read each row in turn until you reach the end of the file.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    // Do whatever you need to do with the data
}
```